# How to permanently color a column in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

How do you set a column or row to always be a certain color even when adding rows or columns?  If you shade/color a column normally, when you add a row or copy paste another cell into that column it will be with no fill or with the fill of the copied cell, respectively.  I want column A to always be blue no matter what.  Can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

You could try conditional formatting:

Select entire sheet.

Conditional Formatting
-> Add New Rule
-> Use a formula to determine which cells to format

Enter formula:

```
=IF(COLUMN(A1)=1,TRUE,FALSE)
```

or just

```
=COLUMN(A1)=1
```

(both the same result - just depends which syntax you feel more comfortable with)

This will check for each cell (you put A1 in because you put it in for the top-left cell of the selection, so A1 because you selected everything - it'll work itself out for the rest of the sheet accordingly)...
...whether its column number is 1 - which will only be the case for column A.

Then pick the formatting you want and click OK, and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

If you place these event routines in the worksheet code area, column **A** will remain blue most of the time:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Range("A:A").Interior.Color = 12611584
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    Range("A:A").Interior.Color = 12611584
End Sub
```

You can temporarily change a column **A** cell's color, but it will return to blue once you change selection.

You can override the effect by disabling Events or by disabling macros in general.

*(using this technique may cause your worksheet to become sluggish.)*

Comment: Thanks.  I was hoping for a solution without using code.